# What is the type of selectionchange listener event parameter?

Tags: typescript

What is the type of [selectionchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event) listener `event` parameter?

```js
// Trying to avoid using any
const handleSelectionChange = (event: any) => {
  console.log(event)
}

document.addEventListener("selectionchange", handleSelectionChange)
```

**UPDATE:** apparently, `Event` is the right type.

Comment: It tells you the answer to this question in the very link you provided: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event#event_type The type is [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event), it doesn't have a specific subclass.

Comment: Oh and you are wrong… using `Event` type, `event.srcElement.activeElement` throws error.

Comment: Don't assume the person *commenting* is the person *downvoting*, you'll usually be wrong. But re your expectation: MDN isn't usually incorrect about these things. Also, any decent IDE should show you the type of handler it's expecting when you type the `,` after the event name.

Comment: I wouldn't expect robust type support for [deprecated properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement). But I suspect you'll have that issue with `target` as well.

Comment: And that really is the type: `https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/cr27ed8g/`

Comment: Interesting… thanks for helping out and sorry for wrong assumption. Using [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) doesn’t work either.